# Multi-line header table in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to create a multi-line header table? What I mean is:
[image]

I'd like to add some filters as I can do with a normal table. Thanks

Comment: Nope, but there are add-ins that can do that. Also [this might help](http://superuser.com/questions/559349/excel-how-to-split-a-data-table-and-reorganise-layout-on-new-tabs)

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look

Comment: Do you have powerpivot plug in installed or are running office 2013 or later?

Comment: I'm using office 2010 and I don't have powerpivot plugin